# Após comando "apt-get dist-upgrade" foi instalado o PHP 7. Como voltar para o 5?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, php-7

Eu uso o Ubuntu 14.04. E quando fui executar esse comando `apt-get dist-upgrade` aqui na minha máquina, ele instalou o PHP 7.

Já removi o PHP 7 assim:

```
apt-get purge php.*
```

Porém quando faço assim:

```
apt-get install php
```

Ele volta a instalar o PHP 7 novamente.

Alguém sabe resolver isso?

## Atualização

Apenas uma informação técnica (não precisa alterar as respostas), é que quando executo `apt-cache policy php5`, aparece isso:

```
php5:
  Instalado: (nenhum)
  Candidato: 7.20151230+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  Tabela de versão:
     7.20151230+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Tenta `sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cli` e outras extensões desejadas sempre iniciando com php5

Comment: @AdemirNuno a gambiarra do PHP começa aí. Se você especifica `apt-get install php5`, ele instala o 7.

Comment: Parece algum "pobrema" no sistema operacional. Conflito nos repositórios., não no php.

Comment: verdade, talvez eu só tenha que remover o ppa do php7. (me parece, pela listinha postada aí em cima, que tem um para a versão 7, outra pra 5.6 e outra pra 5.5).

Comment: @DanielOmine resolvi de um jeito esquisito, veja lá.

Comment: Caso você atualize a versão do Ubuntu para a 16.04, não deixe de ver a solução abaixo, que te possibilita - inclusive - alternar entre as versões 5.6 e 7.0 do PHP. Vale a pena conferir: http://askubuntu.com/a/762161 Abs, Att. AdrianoLeal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de instalar, sempre verifique por pacotes já existentes.

Isso retornará uma lista de pacotes que contenham a palavra PHP, caso existam:

```
>dpkg --get-selections | php
```

Remova os pacotes que precisam ser removidos.

> sudo apt-get remove **nome-do-pacote**

Em negrito, digite o nome do pacote, exatamente como aparece na lista da busca.

**Instalando o repositório**

Adicione o repositório do PHP 5.6 ou outra versão que preferir. No exemplo abaixo, é para a versão 5.6

```
>add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
>apt-get -y update
```

Instalando o PHP

Com o repositório instalado, execute a instalação do PHP:

```
>apt-get -y install php5
```

Isso fará a instalação padrão.

**Extensões do PHP**

Após isso, obviamente você vai querer as extensões mais usadas:

```
>apt-get -y install php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-gd
```

A sintaxe é simples

```
>apt-get -y install php5-nome_da_extensão
```

**Após completar, confira no console**

```
>php -v
```

Mostrará a versão

```
>php -m
```

Mostrará as extensões carregadas

Comment: Daniel, pra que serve o `-y`. Já vi isso várias vezes e não entendi

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o `y` assume que para qualquer opção de prompt será sempre Yes ou Sim, ou seja você não precisará confirmar nada, o prompt irá deixar sempre Yes automaticamente :D

Comment: Serve para automatizar as confirmações. Há instalações que pedem dezenas de confirmações. Se especificar -y, será respondido "sim" em todas as perguntas ,automaticamente. Claro que não deve-se usar sem saber o que está fazendo. Mas nesse caso são apenas perguntas de "pode baixar?", "pode instalar?".. Obviamente vc vai responder "sim" para todas essas perguntas, mas nesse contexto, blz? rsrs

Comment: Então é melhor não usar - na maioria dos casos.

Comment: Sim. Use apenas se vc já souber as perguntas.

Comment: @DanielOmine, isso aqui não está fazendo atualizar. Está informando (sem a opção `-y`) que vai instalar o php7. Primeiro dia de trabalho, essa treta, hein!

Comment: mesmo especificando "install php5"?

Comment: Mesmo especificando. Vou tentar remover o ppa e adicionar de novo :|

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33820/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-daniel-omine).

Answer (score 2):

Como é ubuntu você pode baixar o seu php e fazer a instalação dele, no caso seria assim:

Removendo o seu php atual:

```
apt-get remove --purge yourphppackage
```

Instalando a versão que você deseja:

```
dpkg -i yourphppackage.deb
```

[Lista de versões disponíveis do PHP](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/)

Comment: uma dúvida, isso funcionaria no caso dele? `sudo apt-get install php5`

Comment: Não, porque ele vai constar na lista de pacotes como php7. acabei de ver isso aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se tem a ver com que o @DanielOmine disse sobre a questão de conflito de pacotes, mas a princípio não me parece que o comando `apt-get install php5` funcione para instalar o PHP 5 (o que parece óbvio), mas sim pra instalar a versão mais recente do php.

Talvez seja o ppa que deve ser corrigido para que o php 7 seja instalado através do comando `apt-get install php7` (que não funcionou aqui ainda).

Eu resolvi o problema da seguinte forma.

- Abri a configuração de atualização de software
- Desmaquei as opções da ppa do ondrej referente ao php7

Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]