# Remover PHP do Ubuntu 14

Tags: php, ubuntu

Utilizei os seguintes comandos para remover o PHP do Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get purge php5 php5-cli libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql phpmyadmin
sudo rm -rf /etc/php5
```

Porém ao executar o comando `php -v` na linha de comandos, obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Feb  3 2016 18:12:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Quero remover o PHP completamente.

Comment: Faz tempo que não mexo com o Linux, mas não seria: `sudo apt-get -y purge php.*` OU `sudo apt-get remove "php*"`.

Comment: veja→http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106632/ap%c3%b3s-comando-apt-get-dist-upgrade-foi-instalado-o-php-7-como-voltar-para-o-5

Comment: antes de executar o comando php -v você executou service apache2 restart?

Comment: o comando `php -v` não depende do apache pois o comando vai direto para o binario php.

Comment: Não precisa excluir sua pergunta só por que ela é duplicada. Duplicatas, quando criadas organicamente costumam ser benéficas ao site por mostrarem formas diferentes de se fazer a mesma pergunta, aumentando as chances de alguém com a mesma dúvida encontrar a solução através de uma busca no google, por exemplo. Mas se quiser mantê-la apagada tudo bem também, a escolha é sua.

Comment: @Math certo! A questão que já existe ajudou sim mas só aplicando as soluções que estão nos comentários e todas as respostas. Vou deixar esse comentário caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Ué, a pergunta se "reabriu" sozinha ao você restaurá-la? Ah, já vi o que aconteceu: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/113720/revisions

Comment: @Math quando cliquei ainda não tinha resposta para a pergunta, acreditava que se tratava de outo assunto. Mas após perceber que o erro era outro e que após corrigi-lo e aplicar a solução da outra pergunta o problema foi resolvido, já não dava para voltar atrás. Mas sim, agora considero que é duplicada.

Comment: Sendo assim então eu fechei

Answer (score 5):

Com o comando abaixo, você remove todos os pacotes que o nome comece com `PHP` e tudo relacionado a ele

`sudo apt-get -y purge php.*`

Você pode ver mais sobre isso [aqui](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59886/how-to-compelety-remove-php)

Comment: Olá Rafael, obrigado porém foi preciso mais coisas. Foi necessário remover os binários e fazer o `apt-get autoremove`